# How to pass Variable Values from JS to PHP (not via form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new here. So I'm trying to pass variable values from client to php server. I **looked** this matter up and saw many answers, but most of them regarding sending form values. What I'm trying to do is transfer actual variable values. A very simple example (multiple instances of the following button):

```
 $("#aam").click(function () {
        var e = confirm("Are you sure?")
        if(e == true)
        {
           $(this).hide('slow');
           counter++;
        }
  });
```

Every time a button is clicked the counter goes up by one (after the "if" checks). Say I want to get the counter value to a server, how should it be done. From my search I learned about AJAX but unfortunately couldn't adjust it to my own scenario... 
I tried this as an AJAX request:

```
$("#click_ajax").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'c:/xampp/htdocs/abby/test.php',
       data: {counter}
     });
});
```

With this PHP:

```
<?php 

    $counter = $_POST['counter'];      

    echo $counter

?>
```

Unfortunately it didn't work - Whatever I do, I get an "Notice: Undefined index: counter in C:\xampp\htdocs\abby\test.php on line 9" Error via xampp. Hope someone can assist me. Thanks in advance,

Abby.

Comment: You're almost there, the issue is the format of the object. You need to just change it to `data: { counter: counter }`. See the jQuery docs for more info on AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax. Also note that you will need to run your code on a web server. You'll currently be getting security errors posting to a `File:\\C:\...` path (not to mention the PHP code won't work). You can easily install IIS or XAMPP if you google them.

Comment: in the data it works like this: `data: {key: value, key2: value2}` so you need to add a value to counter. `data: {counter: counter}`

Comment: "c:/xampp/htdocs/abby/test.php" is not a valid URL. PHP will not execute in this context, and also you'll get security errors when trying to call a local file via ajax. It needs to be something like "http://localhost..." etc, as per however your local webserver is configured.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, @keja No, `{ counter }` is pefectly fine as an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions).

Comment: As pointed out by @PeterMader, we were wrong and you JS looks okay. Can you expand on _Unfortunately it didn't work_, does it hit your PHP or does that not even happen?

Comment: @PeterMader Thanks for letting me know. I didn't realise object initialisers had finally been getting some syntactic sugar updates. My other point about running on a webserver stands though

Comment: thanks @PeterMader was not aware that shorthands was added in ES6 :)

Comment: @George When I go with my browser to the php file (via xampp), I get an error message: Notice: Undefined index: counter in C:\xampp\htdocs\abby\test.php on line 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't figure out why PHP not receiving POST data from $.ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459596/cant-figure-out-why-php-not-receiving-post-data-from-ajax-call)

Comment: @PeterMader Thanks for clarifying the object literal matter. I think My php file, as simple as it is, must be wrong.

Comment: @giorgio No, it is not. as PeterMeter said, {coounter} is a correct object literal, so It's not a 'key:value' problem. Please read the posts carefully 
 before claiming it's a duplicate, as it is really counter-intuitive and unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not send correct data thru Ajax request. Try this:

JS:

```
 var ajaxUrl = 'abby/test.php';

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  ajaxUrl, //check if you get in the ajax file
   data: {
     action: "sendCounter",
     counter: counter
   }
}).always(function() {

}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data); // you should get back from the server the counter number 
});
```

PHP (More elegant way of ajax file):

```
if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $strAction = $_POST['action'];
    switch ($strAction)
    {
       case 'sendCounter':
          if (isset($_POST['counter']))
          {
              echo $_POST['counter'];
          }
       break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me. I get an "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abby\test.php on line 16". The basic PHP code I uploaded above, which was approved by other users also gave me an error: "Notice: Undefined index: counter in C:\xampp\htdocs\abby\test.php on line 9". What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I missed a ) on the if inside the case, I will edit now, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Now I don't get an error but it still doesn't show (echo) anything on the php page. Also, why does my basic php code throws an error? Thanks again, Abby

Comment: Try a var_dump on the $_POST and see what you have in there, I think the index counter is not defined because you use data: {counter} syntax instead of data: {counter:counter}. Probably your index is 1. I haven't tried to use your syntax.. Let me know what the var_dump is printing.

Comment: Also i suggest you check the counter variable before send it to ajax. Write console.log(counter); just before the ajax request, I presume that is empty because from your post I do not see where you declare the variable and assign 0 value to it.

Comment: Thanks. The counter has a value. I tried also counter:counter, but it's still the same. I wonder what else it could be... Any other way to send my variables status to the server?

Answer (score -2):

```
$("your-form-id or event-any-id").on("click", function(event)
{    event.preventDefault();
    var post = new FormData( $("#form-id") );
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "POST OR GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: post,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status) {},
        error: function (xhr, desc, err){}
    });
});
```

//more details
//url : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set